How to put the inequality symbol (<=) in the rows of a table with grid.table in R
I can't get the attached table, (<=) to show up as  

The table is variable and has been constructed as follows:
limites1 <- function (m ){
  h1 <- NULL
  for (i2 in 1: m){
    h1 <-c(h1 , paste0(unique(sort(v))[i2],  c( paste0( "<=  x  < " )) ,unique(sort(v))[i2+1] ))
  }
  h1
}

a <- unique(sort(v))[1]
b <- unique(sort(v))[n18]
prueba <- c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(prop.table(table(v)))) )
intervalos1 <- c( paste0("x<",a) ,limites1((1/(mean(unique(sort(v)))/sum(unique(sort(v)))))-1), paste0("x>=",b))


tablasolucion <-data.frame (intervalos1 , prueba)
colnames (tablasolucion) <-c(  "x" ,  'F==P(X<=x)' )
tt <- ttheme_default(core = list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE)),colhead=list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE)))
grid.newpage()
grid.table(tablasolucion, rows = NULL, theme=tt)



It's easier to help if you provide a reproducible (and minimal) example.. But you can parse the plotmath in the data  by adding it at the top level of theme. You also need to correctly form your plotmath statements. Here is a small example which may help: you construct your table: d = data.frame( 'x' = "{2 <= x} < 3", 'F==P(X <= x)'= 1, check.names = FALSE); grid::grid.newpage() ; grid.table(d, theme=ttheme_default(parse=TRUE))

can't you just use the ≤ character? t <- data.frame(x = 'x ≤ 2 < 3', 'F = P(X ≤ x)' = 0.1, check.names = FALSE); grid.newpage(); grid.table(t)

Thank you. I work with "exams2pdf" and each time a different table is generated. The table is generated with "limits1".

Did you answer @rawr?

I don't think plotmath can parse "1<=2<3", but you can use invisible grouping by enclosing the part of expression in {}, so that it tries to parse "{1<=2}<3"
This should work:
h1 <-c(h1 , paste0("{", unique(sort(v))[i2],  c( paste0( "<=x}<" )) ,unique(sort(v))[i2+1] ))


Thank you very much. It works perfectly. It's on the top.
